# Azure HBASE REST API - Issue with Colon Character

Tags: node.js, rest, azure, hbase, azure-hdinsight

Just discovered that the following REST Request to my HDInsight HBase Cluster from outside a Vnet fails:

```
http://example.com:8000/exampletable/1/ExampleColumnFamily:ExampleColumn/content:raw
```

The issue is due to a colon character in the request. HBase cluster gateway by defaults blocks this character.

I would like to create a Node.js Web-Application outside the Azure Vnet (where the Cluster is located in). Does anybody struggle with this issue before? Some solutions?
Microsoft declares this as a bug, and they promised to fix it for the future:

[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bb25dc0f-82b8-49c1-bc5a-d5e506c205b9/azure-hbase-rest-simple-get-failing-for-colfamcol?forum=hdinsight)

Thanks for your help

Kind regards
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas My first idea is changing `:` to `%3A`. But refering to [the issue page](https://github.com/hdinsight/hbase-sdk-for-net/issues/26#issuecomment-132818300), it seems to be not works. I still recommend that you can try to follow the @duoxu comments from the issue page to work around.

Comment: Hi Peter Pan
Thanks a lot for your input. I just found that article that describes on how to integrate an Azure Web App with with an Azure Virtual Network. I think I will give it a try then:
[Article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/)

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas,

There is a workaround that you can provision a linux VM inside the VNET and install nginx to route your requests. In that way you will get rid of hdinsight gateway and you can define your own reroute policies for the coming requests.